# When you publish an add-in via centralized deployment, can you make it visible by default without having to manualy add it via Insert > My Add-ins?

Tags: office-js

This is the part in the manifest that controls the taskpaneButton etc etc. I'm pretty sure you can adjust this to make it happen but need some advise.

```
        <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
      <GetStarted>
        <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
        <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>

        <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
        <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>

        <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
      </GetStarted>
      <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
        <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
        <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
          <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
          <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
            <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
            <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
            <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
            <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
            <Icon>
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
            </Icon>

            <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
              <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
              </Icon>

              <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>
    </DesktopFormFactor>
```

This is for an word addin in office 365 and it would be nice to not have to do the insert procedure for everyone. I'm not certain but I think I have seen a similar question, but I ask it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Will the new feature described at [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) serve your needs? There's a sample at: [Office OOXML EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin)

Comment: Ohh! I was just about to go back to that page - or search for it =) I read it and check out if it could be the solution for us. I have also tried out the possibility to have a separated customtab with the addin, but still the behavior is: sometimes it is shown - other times not. manifest validated with the node module and of course when you upload the manifest via office365 administrator.